# Include formatted subscript in mtext?

Tags: r, axis-labels, subscript

Admittedly I am new to R but I have looked around quite a bit and I can't seem to solve this.

For superscript this works lovely

```
mtext(expression(paste( italic("h") ^ italic("2"))), side=2, line = 2, cex=cexm)
```

but when I try to get a subscript using the same approach

```
mtext(expression(paste(italic("I") [] italic("a"))),side=2, line=2,cex=cexm)
```

or

```
mtext(expression(paste(italic("I"), italic(["a"]))),side=2, line=2,cex=cexm)
```

plus several other variations on this theme

R keeps telling me that there is an unexpected `[`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, apologies if this is addressed elsewhere but I did not succeed in finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance the paste call is entirely superfluous since the argument is a valid R expression:

```
 mtext(expression( italic("h") ^ italic("2")), side=2, line = 2) # works
```

In the second instance `paste` is also unnecessary:

```
 mtext(expression( italic("I") [italic("a")] ),side=2, line=2,cex=cexm)
```

The argument to the plotmath-"[" function needs to be inside the paired `"[]"`-symbols.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was one variation I had not thought of, and yes I see now that paste is indeed superfluous, I am still very new to this whole thing.