# Subscript in simple base R graph using mtext

Tags: r, axis-labels

Take a very simple example.

```
x <- 1:10
plot(x)
mtext(paste("Test n=",length(x),""), side=3)
```

We generate a simple plot. Now lets say I want to include a **subscript x** between the `n` and the `=`. I think I need to use `expression`, but I cant get the correct format

```
plot(x)
mtext(expression(paste("Test n[x]=",length(x),"")), side=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why expression?

```
plot(x)
mtext(paste("Test n[x]=",length(x),""), side=3)
```

Comment: I want the x to be subscripted. With your code it doesnt subscript. From what I have seen, we need expression for the subscript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664385/include-formatted-subscript-in-mtext?rq=1